# Wrong score of particular user in newest question list

Tags: bug

[image: Image of newest question list]

In above image in highlighted area, score of particular user is mismatched with this below image

which shows the orginal question.

[image: original question iamge]

What will be reason for this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are **different users**.

The one in List is who modified the <strike>question</strike> answer, the one in the question is who asked the question.

If you look at the list, then it shows, "modified by".

You are talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704724/onitemclicklistener-connected-with-2-spinners)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

soulreaver modified [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20705179/752320) at that time. The time shown on the recent question list is the last edit/revision of that question *or any answer* to it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not looking at the Newest Questions view, you're looking at the "Active" view, which shows all activity. The user displayed is the user whose activity caused its inclusion on the list, not whoever originally asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. Editing a question / answer pushes it to the top of the **Active** questions list. In this case, *soulreaver* modified his answer and that pushed the quested to the top of the list.

You can verify this by looking at the [question's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20704724/timeline):

[image]